# ReactJS componentWillReceiveProps not triggering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

I'm implementing a slider off of https://github.com/akiran/react-slick

I have custom child components that need to update their state when the parent updates. When I load the slides in normally, eg:

```
<Slider ref={c => this.slider = c } {...settings}>
  <div key={1}>
    <Slide1 key={1} formData={this.state.formData} />
  </div>
  ...
</Slider>
```

componentWillReceiveProps works fine. However, when I load the slides dynamically based off the example [here](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/master/examples/DynamicSlides.js), these lifecycle events are never called, even after state is updated in the parent.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        slides: [
            <div key={1}>
                <Slide1 key={1} formData={this.state.formData} />
            </div>,
            ....
        ]
    )};
}


<Slider ref={c => this.slider = c } {...settings}>
  {this.state.slides.map(function (slide, i) {
    return slide
  })}
</Slide>
```

With the components loading like this, componentWillReceiveProps never gets called, even after state is updated.

What am I missing? I don't need Redux to manage this do I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well first of all, it is a very bad idea to attempt storing actual React elements in the state, there you should store only pure data which you in turn use in `render` method to compose the markup.

Secondly, `componentWillReceiveProps` is not called in your case, because your Slide1s are being rendered there for the first time, they are being mounted onto the DOM, but `componentWillReceiveProps` can be called only for already mounted components, see [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops).

Comment: Thanks Dan. Still new to react, but storing jsx in state felt wrong. Is there any other way to go about impending https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/master/examples/DynamicSlides.js if I have multiple custom components that need to be rendered in the slides? Eg: Slide1, Slide2, etc?

Comment: Well it depends on whether those Slide1, Slide2... are similar to each other. Based on the name and the fact you use them inside Slider, I bet they are. Forget about Slide 1,2,3 and create just one which is generic enough.

Comment: They're actually each completely different forms. There's really no commonality unfortunately.

Comment: That's hard to believe because of the naming. Anyway, if they differ so much, their rendering either shouldn't be so dynamic like mapping them from some array to elements which are completely different, or create the generic rendering mechanism (component ideally).If you wan't to, provide your code via CodePen or something, otherwise I can't tell you much more except for general phrases.

Comment: Your first comment was actually incredibly helpful. I'd read that in the docs 100 times, but for some reason it never clicked until I read it here. I think I've got it solved by passing a list of slide names in the array instead of the jsx elements. Then in the .map, I'm just checking which slide it is and rendering that to the screen.

I don't think this is the most elegant solution, but it's an incredibly unique use case and the time is running short.

Really appreciate the help. Thank you!